# ReportViewer column group page break

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

I need to generate a daily employee attendance report using ASP.NET ReportViewer. It must be grouped by month, meaning I have to set page break based on the `monthName` field.

I come up with the following design in my RDLC report:

[image]

The result is:
[image]

At first, everything is fine. The first page shows the attendance for the month of January, from Jan. 1 to 31. Clicking on the "Next Page" button on the report shows the employee attendance record for the next month (i.e. February.)

But employees can be quite numerous thus it is better to be rendered as a row instead of as a column. No problem. I can just redesign the report and again, set the page break to `[monthName]` such as:

[image]

To my surprise, it doesn't work. I found out in MSDN that **page break is not allowed in column group**!

My question is:

1. What's the problem with setting column group page breaks? Why did
   *they* set this limitation?
2. What's the workaround to accomplish this? I'm sure you people have
   also tried to accomplish the same task and succeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I'm afraid I don't know the reason to why *they* do anything. There are many more unnecessary limitations just like this one. Which is the only reason I can think of for people to use Crystal Reports over SSRS.
2. There is however always a workaround. Not always simple but when there is a will, there usually is a way.
   I'll do my best to explain a possible workaround below:

---

**Workaround**

1. You start by adding a new `Tablix` to your report that has only a single column and row. You bind this table to your dataset.
2. Add a Row Group on `monthName` and re-size the tablix to be the same size as your Report Body.
3. Place a `Rectangle` in the cell of the tablix.  And set the `PageBreak` property of the rectangle, `BreakLocation` to *End*.
4. Place your original table in the rectangle. Then adjust the height of the rectangle so it fits around the table perfectly.

Here is an example of the Document Outline:
[image: Document Outline]

This makes your table groups wrapped inside a rectangle. This rectangle is grouped on the `monthName` and ommits a page-break at the end which will cause the reporter to print a single group per page.

If you have any trouble, just leave a comment.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I noticed that the the employees who have null `logCnt` in a month don't appear in the page. I needed to show all the employees with or without log/s. Previously it worked without using this workaround. What do I need to configure in order to produce my desired result?

Comment: If the grouping from before before worked, just try and sue the same grouping in the outer table. The rectangle is responsible for adding the breaks anyway, so you shouldn't have the problem you had before. Another solution would be to alter your SQL query that fetches your data. Use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and catch the null values in the necessary column like this:  `ISNULL(logCnt, 0)`. This would make sure that there are records in the group, even if they are empty.

Comment: Hope you'll answer my future questions about ReportViewer too :)